# convert non balanced binary search tree to red black tree

Tags: binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

Is it possible to convert a non balanced BST (the size of the tree is n and the height is h) to RBT in time complexirty of O(n) and space complexity of O(h)?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of nodes before hand this is doable, knowing the number of nodes tells you the height of the target RB tree (regardless of what the original tree height).

Therefore you can simply 'peel' nodes off the original tree one-by-one starting from the minimum and place them in the correct tree slot. The easiest way to do this will end up with every row except for a potentially empty bottom row black. (That is, if you have a tree with 7 nodes they will all be black but if you have a tree with 6 the first 2 rows will be black and the bottom row will have 3 red nodes).

This will take O(n) time - to visit each node in the original tree - and O(h) space because you will need to keep track of some bookkeeping depending on where you are in the process.

And note this will *only* work if you know the number of nodes in the original tree, as it depends on knowing which nodes will be in the bottom row of the produced tree.

Comment: I don't know the number of nodes, I solved it already by convert the BST to doubly linked list ,made a balanced BST from it and made it RBT. It took me O(n) time and O(1) space. Thanks anyway.